# BigQuery table schema types not being translated correctly in apache beam

Tags: python, google-bigquery, casting, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

There is a [bug](https://github.com/apache/beam/issues/28151) in the python Apache Beam SDK for BigQuery currently which translates BQ `TIMESTAMP` incorrectly to BQ `DATETIME`. This [seems to have been fixed](https://github.com/apache/beam/pull/26889), but I have a feeling it may be in a pre-release not the latest stable release (2.49.0).

This appears in an error that describes an input/output schema mismatch when converted. This error only applies when using the Storage Write API. The legacy streaming API works fine.

The SDK converts `LOGICAL_TYPE<beam:logical_type:micros_instant:v1>` to `DATETIME`, not `TIMESTAMP`. I was wondering if anyone has found a workaround for now until the (relatively) new bug is fixed?

Comment: May be not a possible workaround, however, please do take a look at Storage Read API - https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/built-in/google-bigquery/#storage-api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone with the same issue, add this line before writing to BigQuery

```py
# imports
from apache_beam.typehints.schemas import LogicalType, MillisInstant

# logical type mapping
LogicalType.register_logical_type(MillisInstant)
```

The Apache Beam devs are aware of the issue and are working to find a more permanent solution.